# Windows 7 renaming account name to a new name, still shows old name

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

In windows 7, I have tried to do the following, in order to rename my account name to a new name:

1. control panel -> account details -> rename to a new name
2. regedit -> rename everything containing my old name to the new name
3. C:\Users -> rename the folder from old name to new name
4. reboot

However, I receive some errors sometimes when trying to edit/delete files, saying "you need -old name- administration permission to modify/delete this file" and it won't let me do it in any way. If I reboot the system, I can then modify/delete the file and the permission error is gone.

Also in task manager, I can see all processes are running with old name under "User Name" column.

What did I miss there?

Comment: This might be a little mess already. Are you trying to change you "Name" from Bob to Robert or are you worried about changing your profile from C:\Users\Bob to C:\Users\Robert or both?

Comment: @Refurb both of them

Comment: if you want to change user name to another one, we could run "netplwiz" and, click your existing account to change user name and full name to a new one. After that, we should reboot computer to make it apply.

Comment: @joy and this will also change everything related? c:\users\directory  , process names, authorizations etc?